# Seemingly incorrect answer from mosaicCalc::antiD in R

Tags: r

I'm using `antiD` from the `mosaicCalc` package to find a symbolic integral in R, but it seems to be making a mistake.

That is,

`antiD(a * (1-exp(-b * Time)) ~ Time )`

is returning:

`a * 1 * Time - 1/(-b) * exp(-b * Time) + C`

which I think is missing `a` from the second term.

If instead I multiply out the LHS and use:

`antiD(a - a*exp(-b * Time) ~ Time )`

then I get this:

`a * Time - a * 1/(-b) * exp(-b * Time) + C`

which is correct.  Is the package making a mistake in the first case, or am I missing something?

**Edit:**
This was a bug in mosaicCalc version 0.5.1 (the current CRAN version), which apparently has now been fixed in the beta branch on Github, although I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: It does look strange. a slightly simpler example of the issue is that `antiD(a * (1+Time) ~ Time )` gives `a * 1 * Time + 1/2 * Time^2 + C`